# Creating regional snapshots with GCP .Net client library

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, snapshot, google-cloud-compute-engine

I'm working on GCP through their .Net client library *Google.Cloud.Compute.V1*.

I'm creating new Snapshots with `SnapshotsClient.InsertAsync` command using the example provided in the official docs:

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1.SnapshotsClient#Google_Cloud_Compute_V1_SnapshotsClient_InsertAsync_System_String_Google_Cloud_Compute_V1_Snapshot_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_

```
SnapshotsClient snapshotsClient = await SnapshotsClient.CreateAsync();
Snapshot snapshotResource = new Snapshot()
{
   Name = "#SNAPSHOT_NAME#",
   SourceDisk = "#SOURCE_DISK#",
};
var response = await snapshotsClient.InsertAsync("#PROJET_ID#", snapshotResource);
var completedResponse = await response.PollUntilCompletedAsync();
Operation result = completedResponse.Result;
```

and it works well.
My problem is that it creates multi-regional snapshots and puts them in US, whereas what I want is to create regional snapshots (for example under *us-central1*).

The only relevant property that I see in the *Snapshot* model is *StorageLocations*, and the docs don't state that it is `[Output Only]` like they do for other properties, however when I try to assign a new value for it I get:

`Property or indexer 'Snapshot.StorageLocations' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Can you please help me understand how to create a regional snapshot with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take an array of strings,
You can use create it using this example:

```
Snapshot snapshotResource = new()
{
    Name = GetNameForNewSnapshot(sourceDisk, zone),
    SourceDisk = sourceDisk,
    StorageLocations = { "us-west1", "us-central1" }
};
```